# Using Google Analytics (or similar service) to track access to offline HTML files?

Tags: google-analytics, tracking

Is it possible to add code to a **static**, local HTML file on my computer, so that whenever I open the local file with a web browser (`file:///C/Users/...`), and assuming that the computer is connected to the Internet, my access will be tracked using Google Analytics or a similar service?

Comment: Can you tell us why, having some context around this would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution, although messy, is to have a iframe, set to a tiny size calling a page on a server which has google analytics. I imagine this is to allow you to do some sort of project tracking, Google Analytics would allow you to have a breakdown of time spent etc.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what exactly you want to track. [ManicTime](http://www.manictime.com/) is an application which can record everything that is done on a computer like opening documents, computer uptime, visited websites and so on.